# Characterize ideals in $\mathbb{F}_l[x]/(x-1) \oplus \mathbb{F}_l[x]/(\frac{x^p-1}{x-1})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals, finite-fields, coding-theory

Let $p,l \in \mathbb{N}$ be prime, and assume that $ord_p(l) = p-1$; that is $l$ is a primitive pth root of unity.

It is known that in this case the ring $R := \mathbb{F}_l[x]/(x^p-1)$ is with

$R \simeq \mathbb{F}_l[x]/(x-1) \oplus \mathbb{F}_l[x]/(\frac{x^p-1}{x-1})$.

Hence this ring $R$ has only two non-trivial ideals.

I'd like to know what their dimensions are.

My thinking is this -

the ideal $I_1 = \{(x,0): x \in \mathbb{F}_l[x]/(x-1) \}$ of $\mathbb{F}_l[x]/(x-1) \oplus \mathbb{F}_l[x]/(\frac{x^p-1}{x-1})$, is of dimension $p-1$ because the dimension of the quotient ring $[\mathbb{F}_l[x]/(x-1) \oplus \mathbb{F}_l[x]/(\frac{x^p-1}{x-1})] / I_1$ is $dim_{\mathbb{F}_l}(R) - dim_{\mathbb{F}_l}(\mathbb{F}_l[x]/(x-1)) = p -1$.

Similarly $dim(I_2) = p - (p-1) = 1$.

Is this a correct argument, can it be made more rigorous and is this what is meant by the dimension of these ideals?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the full context, but normally I would expect "dimension" refers to the dimension of the ideal itself (as a vector space), not the dimension of the quotient by the ideal.  So your dimensions are backwards: $I_1$ has dimension $1$, since it is a $1$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_l$, and $I_2$ has dimension $p-1$ similarly.

Comment: for example we know the dimension of $(x-1)$ in $R$ is $p - deg(gcd(x^p - 1, x-1)) = p-1$, so this agrees with your definition of ideal, right?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but $(x-1)$ and $I_2$ are literally the same ideal, so it should not be a surprise that they both have dimension $p-1$.